# concat - audio files using FFmpeg not working in above Android 5.1

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, concatenation, android-mediarecorder

I am using [FFmpeg](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) to concat three Audio file combine into one

1. audio.m4a (get from assets)
2. Recorded audio.m4a (Record using MediaRecorder)
3. audio.m4a (get from assets)

its works fine in below Android 5.1 but not working on above Android 5.1,
In above 5.1 recorded audio file not concat (its playing good when i play from saved internal storage its not corrupt recording).

I am using following command to concat audio files.

```
File mergedFile = new File(cacheDir + "/" + String.format("merged_file_%s.m4a", System.currentTimeMillis()));

final String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[]{ /* this concat only 1st audio*/
            "ffmpeg",
            "-f",
            "concat",
            "-i",
            list, /* text file which contains full path of audio files*/
            "-c",
            "copy",
            mergedFile.toString()};


    final String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[]{  /*its working but not concat recorded file*/
            "-y",
            "-i",
            "concat:" + getStaticFilePath() + "|" + getRecordedFilePath() + "|" + getStaticFilePath(),
            "-c",
            "copy",
            mergedFile.toString()};


    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
    }

    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(ffmpegCommand, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + ffmpegCommand);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {

                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + ffmpegCommand);
                Log.d(TAG, "Processing...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + ffmpegCommand);
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
```

list is a text file contains path of all audio which i concat

```
#ffmpeg.txt
file '/storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder/radioStatic.m4a'
file '/storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder/recordedFile.m4a'
file '/storage/emulated/0/AudioRecorder/radioStatic.m4a'
```

Comment: Above Android 5.1 or 6.0 needs runtime permission for accessing storage have get them?

Comment: already set runtime permission for that.

Comment: i have found alternate solution for this issue.  I play all three audio in sequence using `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
  val cmd = arrayOf("-y", "-i", audio1!!.path, "-i", audio2!!.path, "-filter_complex"," 
   [0:a] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a]","-map","[a]", "-c:a","mp3", outputLocation.path)
```